# Adding labels as a new column to a list in R

Tags: r

Can you please help me to set labels in a list as new dataframe in R. For example, x is my list.
head(x) is giving me the following output:

```
head(x)
[[1]]
  A B
  0 0 

[[2]]
  C D E F
  0 1 0 0
```

I want to create a data frame like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! TIA!

Comment: Lists (that aren't also data frames or possibly something else) can't have row names, I'm fairly sure. An object has to have a dimensions attribute to have row names.

Comment: Try `stack(unlist(x))`

Comment: @markus, It works like a charm! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are no rows to name unless your list is a `data.frame`. Try `x <- as.data.frame(x)` just before your cbind.

Answer to updated question :

```
l1 <- c(A=0, B=1)
l2 <- c(C=0,D=1,E=0,F=0)

x <- list(l1,l2)

x <- as.data.frame(c((x[[1]]), (x[[2]])))
colnames(x) <- c("X")
```

Outputs:

> ```
>   X
> A 0
> B 1
> C 0
> D 1
> E 0
> F 0
> ```

Here you can use your original code:

```
x <- cbind(EMAIL=rownames(x), x)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
>   EMAIL X
> A     A 0
> B     B 1
> C     C 0
> D     D 1
> E     E 0
> F     F 0
> ```

Comment: It looks like you first need to make sure that [[1]] and [[2]] are of the same length, otherwise it's not clear (to R) what the final cbind should look like. For instance, rows >= 5 would not have a value for [[1]]. Try creating a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I guess, my question was wrongly asked, I have modified the question now. I haven't worked with list in R before.

Comment: my data is very huge. your solution works very well for small dataset. But thanks a lot for helping me out. :)